# What layout to choose?

Tags: android, android-layout

In the layout there are three buttons in top row, one image in second row and three buttons in the third row. Now what layout shall I use so that the layout does not get distorted when seen in different mobiles of differeent screen size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can choose [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) or nested [Linear Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html).To support different screen sizes [read these lessons](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html).